# Keywords for defining constructs in programming languages

Tags: design, programming-languages

I'm designing a language conceptually similar to Go.

In Go, for example, the keyword `func` is used for defining functions:

```
func abs (a int) uint { ... }
```

Same for defining types.

However, I was thinking of a grammar that doesn't consider these keywords.

For example:

```
abs (a int => uint) { ... }
```

Or, for structures:

```
Tree {size int; age int}
```

What's wrong with such a syntax?  Are there some potential problems that could be encountered?

For example, I thought that if there was a construct that would use the same grammar as a struct, such as an interface, it would be vague (is this a struct or an interface)?

Comment: Do you know how C/C++/C#/Java declare functions? `type funcName() {}`, for example: `int getNumber() {}`. This looks pretty close to what you're asking.

Comment: You could also look at Haskell as a model.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Please don't do this. Keywords are important.

Answer (score 4):

> What's wrong with such a syntax?

There are two basic things that can be wrong with such a syntax:

1. **It's ambiguous** - identifier, parens, block is a common syntax that can be used for blocks, class definitions and other things. You're likely to run into cases where your grammar cannot distinguish between function declarations and these other things. Or if it can, it uses dirty tricks. Or that it can, but does really poorly in partial-parsing situations (intellisense, debugging/error reporting).
2. **It's confusing** - even if the compiler can grok the source, humans cannot. If the function declaration looks too similar to other things, people will get confused. If people get confused, they'll either not use your language or start adopting (conflicting) idioms to clarify the syntax.